# Android Customize Lock Screen Cannot FullScreen

Tags: android, fullscreen

I'm working on a customized lock screen,
I wanna add and option to hide status bar (full screen)
However, I've tried the following code (in my lock screen Activity), which doesn't work at all,
my app is "behind" the status bar...

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and

```
<activity android:name=".lockscreenactivity" 
        android:label="@string/lock_screen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar" 
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
        android:process=":LockScreen"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" 
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

anyone knows why?
(the above code works for my other activities.)

Comment: working for other activities means ?? can you elaborate ?

Comment: my other activities(not serve as lock screen activity) can go full screen without problem

Comment: I guess Android forces status bar to show when screen is off.

Answer (score 0):

correct this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"
```

to

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: but i wanna use current wallpaper as my background, and I've tried your suggestion, still not working.